# Sequence of Lipschitz maps that converge pointwise to a Lipscthiz functions must have bounded Lipschitz constants?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n:M \to M$ be a sequence of Lipschitz maps in a metric space $(M,d)$. Assume that we know that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converge pointwise to $f:M\to M$ that is also a Lipschitz map. Let $L_n$ denote the Lipschitz constant of each $f_n$, that is, $L_n=\sup_{x\neq y}\dfrac{d(f(x),f(y))}{d(x,y)}$. Then, can we deduce that the sequence $\{L_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded?

I expect this being false, but I can't find a counterexample. Maybe there is hope to argue that converging pointwise to a Lipscthiz map $f$ must bound the Lipschitz constants of the $\{f_n\}$ sequence (or otherwise we would have a contradiction)?

Comment: It's false. Take $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\leq n$, $f_n(n+1) = n$, $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\geq n+2$ and piecewise linear in between. This sequence converges to the zero function, but the lipschitz constant of $f_n$ is $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_n(x)=\frac 1n\sin(n^2x)$, $f(x)=0$. Then $f_n\to f$ uniformly. All the functions are Lipschitz. However $f_n'(x)=n\cos(n^2x)$ so $L_n=n$.

Comment: Thank you! That is a good counterexample because we even have uniform convergence. By the way, $f_n'(x)=n cos(n^2x)$ (cosinus instead of sinus, right)? Maybe you should edit the answer.

Comment: @KnightOfTrade, of course. :-)